# The problem about the $.ajax in jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

first I use $.ajax to load html code in my html page

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "test.xml",
        async: false,   //without set the async to false could cause problem,I also don't konw why
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 2000,
        success: function (xml) {
             var $temp_code = $(xml).find("test[id='" + i+ "']").find("html_code").html();
            //the html code is like <div class="test"></div>……
             $($temp_code).appendTo($(".wrapper")).show();
    });
}
```

The code could work alright in page ,html code in xml could be read properly .Then I want give each "test" div bind a click function

like

```
        $(".test").click(function () {
            alert("");
        });
```

but this could not success,click each "test" alert nothing

then I try to put it into $.ajax complete like:

```
$.ajax({
   ……
   complete:function(){
            $(".test").click(function () {
                alert("");
            });
   }
})
```

This could only work for the first "test" div ,it means only click the first "test" could alert

How can I solve this problem?Let the click work in each "test",

Thank you!

Comment: can you show what the xml file contains?

Comment: in first code of click event you are getting any javascript error

Comment: @Vivek:In fact, the original code is not like this,bacause I have ask in here,so I simply the code ,and I have not test it .But I think it have express what I want to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want it something like this, which is also *much* faster since it uses the result of that AJAX request (which should be the same) for the loop, rather than making the request repeatedly, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "test.xml",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function (xml) {
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
      var $temp_code = $(xml).find("test[id='" + i+ "']").find("html_code").html();
      $($temp_code).appendTo($(".wrapper")).show().find(".test").click(function () {
        alert("");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

What this does is bind the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) only to those elements it just added, the `.test` `<div>` elements created by `$($temp_code)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .live() (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: I've found that .live() can be unreliable, while $(document).delegate() always works, although it may be at a larger performance cost, but I've not run into any issues where thats been apparent.

Answer (score 0):

In the first script fragment, you need to refer to `xml.d` to access the contents of the return from your GET.

```
success: function (xml) {
             var $temp_code = $(xml.d).find("test[id='" + i+ "']").find("html_code").html();
```

I think that this will also allow you click handler to work.

Comment: This is an XML request, not a JSON one wrapped in a `d` property by Microsoft :)

Comment: In that case this answer doesn't help!  My bad.